# How to use reducer in neasted array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

trying to delete id:2 car from my mongodb database. using react redux, my question is how to check dispatch id equal to car id in reducer?

**button**
`<button onClick={this.handleDeleteCar(carID : data.id)>delete</button>`

**data log**

```
carview:
       [ 
         { id: 5c7496f0def4602bf413ea9a,
            parentId: 5c7496f0def4602bf413ea97,
            car: [
                   {
                     id: 2,
                     name: bmw
                   },
                   {
                     id:3,
                     name: amg
                    }
                 ]
          }
        ]
```

**reducer**

```
case carConstants.car_DELETE_REQUEST:
return {...state,items: state.items.map(car =>car.id === action.id
        ? { ...car, deleting: true }
        : car
    )
  };
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
return {
  ...state,
  items: state.items.filter((car) => car.id !== action.id)
}
```

**EDIT:**

In your case, you can use an Array.prototype.filter nested inside an Array.prototype.map:

```
return {
  ...state,
  carView: state.carView.map((view) => {
    return {
      ...view,
      car: view.car.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id)
    }
  })
}
```

This can become quickly messy if you deal with deeply nested objects and it's a good idead to [try to keep your state normalized in redux](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)

Comment: i just updated with carview array, my question is is it okey with filter ?

Comment: Oh yeah you're right first carview map then car ! Sorry I didn't see your second comment

Comment: its very difficult to me , if your free please give me a solution using normalized, then i can learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Above answer using Array.filter is a good one, but if that won't fit your use case you can use a nested findIndex check.

```js
let state = [ 
     { id: "5c7496f0def4602bf413ea9a",
        parentId: "5c7496f0def4602bf413ea97",
        car: [
               {
                 id: 4,
                 name: "bmw"
               },
               {
                 id:5,
                 name: "amg"
                }
             ]
      },
     { id: "5c7496f0def4602bf413ea9a",
        parentId: "5c7496f0def4602bf413ea97",
        car: [
               {
                 id: 2,
                 name: "bmw"
               },
               {
                 id:3,
                 name: "amg"
                }
             ]
      }
    ];

const action = { type: 'example', id: 2 }

const index = state.findIndex(({car}) => car.findIndex(({id}) => id === action.id) !== -1);

if (index === -1) {
  // you would probably return current state here realistically
  throw new Error('no index');
}
console.log(index);
state = [ ...state.slice(0, index), ...state.slice(index + 1)];
console.log(state);
```